# Esperar a una respuesta para continuar un for Node.js

Tags: nodejs

Buenas les comento mi duda:
tengo una función en `node.js` que lo que hace es recoger todos los clientes de una base de datos `SQL`. Estoy usando el paquete `mssql` para esto pero el tema es que por cada cliente debo hacer otra petición para añadir mas datos a cada uno de ellos. El problema es que la petición es asincrónica y no espera a recibir la respuesta para seguir con el siguiente, aquí el ejemplo:

```
exports.getClients = function(req, res) {

    var response = []

    new sql.Request()
        .execute('getClients')
        .then(function(clientes) {

            var clientesArray = clientes[0]

            for (var i = 0; i < clientesArray.length; i++) {

                new sql.Request()
                    .execute('getDireClients')
                    .then(function(dirents) {

                          //aquí es donde se añaden los datos a un cliente                                

                    }).catch(function(err) {
                        res.json({
                            "error": err.message
                        })
                    });
            }

        }).catch(function(err) {
            res.json({
                "error": err.message
            })
        });
};
```

¿Cómo lo he resuelto?
Pues haciendo una función recursiva que fuera recorriendo el array de clientes por un indice y una vez que dicho indice sea igual al tamaño del array que devuelva la respuesta. (Comparto por si le sirve a alguien)

```
  exports.getClients = function(req, res) {

        var response = []
        var addedClientsCount = 0

        new sql.Request()
            .execute('getClients')
            .then(function(clientes) {

                var clientesArray = clientes[0]
                addDirentsToClient(clientesArray , addedClientsCount, res, response)

            }).catch(function(err) {
                res.json({
                    "error": err.message
                })
            });
    };

function addDirentsToClient (clients, addedClientsCount, res, response) {

      new sql.Request()
          .execute('getDireClients')
          .then(function(dirents) {

          if (addedClientsCount >= clients.length) {              
              res.json(response)
          }else{
            //aquí añado los datos al cliente, he suprimido 
            //  esta parte porque es larga
            response.push(clients[i])
            addedClientsCount = addedClientsCount + 1
            addDirentsToClient(clients, addedClientsCount, res, response)
          }

      }).catch(function(err) {
          res.json({
              "error": err.message
          })
      });
}
```

Entonces mi **pregunta** es:

¿ Se puede hacer esto pero con el primer ejemplo, es decir, con un for ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, no creo que puedas hacer eso en un `for`, además, si tu arreglo es medianamente grande, un recorrido recursivo terminará por explotar con un stackoverflow (sin el .com).

Me parece que lo que estas buscando es `Promise.all`, a `Promise.all` le puedes pasar un arreglo de promises que puedes ir llenado en el for, y cuando hagas `Promise.all(miArregloDePromise).then( ... )`, en el `then` puedes asumir que recibes un arreglo con el resultado de cada promise que le añadiste.

[Promise.all en MDN (en inglés)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

Answer (score 1):

Al final conseguí hacerlo con el paquete Promise como bien comenta @yms:

```
function addDirentsToClientes(clientes, res) {

  var count = 0
  var clientesDirents = []

    return clientes.reduce(function(promise) {

        return promise.then(function() {

        return new sql.Request()
              .input('codcli', sql.VarChar(8), clientes[count].CODCLI)
              .execute("getDirentsByCodCli")
              .then(function(dirents) {

                var cliente = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(clientes[count]))
                count++

                cliente.dirents = dirents[0]
                clientesDirents.push(cliente)

                if (count >= clientes.length){
                  res.json(clientesDirents)
                }

              }).catch(function(err) {
                  res.json({
                      "error": err.message
                  })
              });
        });
    }, Promise.resolve());
}
```

Si alguien me dice una forma mejor de hacer lo anterior se lo agradezco.
Muy agradecido @yms